# Unable to change password for root account ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I have the following error:

```
{"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": 
 {"append_privs": false, "check_implicit_admin": true, "config_file": "/root/.my.cnf", "connect_timeout": 30, "encrypted": false, "host": "rothko", "host_all": false, "login_host": "localhost", "login_password": "", "login_port": 3306, "login_unix_socket": null, "login_user": "root", "name": "root", "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", "priv": "*.*:ALL,GRANT", "sql_log_bin": true, "ssl_ca": null, "ssl_cert": null, "ssl_key": null, "state": "present", "update_password": "always", "user": "root"}, "module_name": "mysql_user"}, 
  "item": "rothko", 
   "msg": "unable to connect to database, 
    check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. 
    Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"}
```

These are my playbook instructions and what I've tried:

```
#    - name: Create .my.cnf file with root password credentials
#      become: yes
#      template: src=".my.cnf.j2" dest="/root/.my.cnf" owner=root group=root mode=0600
#    - name: Restart mysql
#      service: name=mysqld state=restarted
#    - name: Change root user password on first run
#      mysql_user:
#        name=root
#        host=localhost
#        password={{ mysql_root_password }}
#        priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT
    - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
      become: yes
      mysql_user:
        login_user=root
        login_password=''
        name=root
        host="{{ item }}"
        password="{{ mysql_root_password }}"
        check_implicit_admin=yes
        priv="*.*:ALL,GRANT"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - localhost
      ignore_errors: true
```

This is a well known problem and I 've found a few questions that treat it but there was no solution for me:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444306/ansible-idempotent-mysql-installation-playbook/16446163#16446163)
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444306/ansible-idempotent-mysql-installation-playbook)
- [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597926/install-mysql-with-ansible-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Either you've set the root password in your now commented out tasks or you've installed MySQL 5.7 which provides a randomly generated root password (can be found in `/var/log/mysqld.log`). Either way you can't login without that root password.

Comment: To the mute downvoters, if you downvote, it would be helpful to cite the reasons so I can improve the question or know what I can't ask.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a "well known problem"; the links you provide are not to people having the same issue as you (at least, as you've described it).  Your problem is that you haven't provided the correct credentials to MySQL.  As @ydaetskcoR says, either you've set it elsewhere (and aren't passing it along now), or it was set for you, and you need to go find it.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov It's all well and good "... and you need to go find it" where exactly? It's not something that you just set elsewhere, it is a config made for a user. I know what is my problem, but not what is the solution.

Comment: ydaetskcoR told you a place to look, but you haven't shown any indication of having tried that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some more info here: [Change mysql root password on Centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510184/change-mysql-root-password-on-centos7)

I try to do some ansible stuff

```
    - name: Stop MySQL
      service: name=mysqld state=stopped
    - name: set environment variables
      shell: systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
    - name: Start MySQL
      service: name=mysqld state=started
    - name: sql query
      command:  mysql -u root --execute="UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('toto') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';"
    - name: sql query flush
      command:  mysql -u root --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
    - name: Stop MySQL
      service: name=mysqld state=stopped
    - name: unset environment variables
      shell: systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
    - name: Start MySQL
      service: name=mysqld state=started
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Full credit to @glmrenard; here's a version I adapted for Percona server 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
---
#Reset MySQL root password
- name: Stop MySQL
  systemd:
    name: mysql
    state: stopped

- name: set environment variables
  shell: systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"

- name: Start MySQL
  systemd:
    name: mysql
    state: started

- name: Reset root PW
  command: mysql -u root --execute="UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('{{ mysql_rootpw }}') WHERE User = 'root' AND (Host = 'localhost' OR Host = '127.0.0.1');"

- name: Flush MySQL privileges
  command: mysql -u root --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES"

- name: Stop MySQL
  systemd:
    name: mysql
    state: stopped

- name: Unset environment variables
  shell: systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS

- name: Start MySQL
  systemd:
    name: mysql
    state: started
```