# Ansible access denied for 'root@localhost' error

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am trying to create a mysql database through Ansible playbook. After reading several threads & questions over here, I have created my playbook like this -

```
---
- name: "Install Packages"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  vars:
    mysql_root_password: Test@1123

  tasks:

  - name: Install basic packages
    apt:
      name:
      - vim
      - curl
      - python3-pip
      - mysql-server
      - libmysqlclient-dev
      - python-pymysql
      state: latest
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - name: start & enable mysql Server
    service:
      name=mysql
      state=started
      enabled=yes

  - name: checking RabbitMQ & mysql Server status
    command: systemctl status "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
    - mysql
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: showing mysql Server status
    debug:
     var: result

  - name: Install pip modules
    pip:
      name:
      - pymysql
      - virtualenv
      state: present
      executable: /usr/bin/pip3

  - name: create /root/.my.cnf with password credentials
    blockinfile:
      path: /root/.my.cnf
      block: |
        [client]
        user=root
        password={{ mysql_root_password }}

        [mysql]
        user=root
        password={{ mysql_root_password }}

        [mysqldump]
        user=root
        password={{ mysql_root_password }}

        [mysqldiff]
        user=root
        password={{ mysql_root_password }}
      create: yes

  - name: "Mysql Configuration - Resetting RootPassword"
    mysql_user:
      login_user: root
      login_password: ''
      name: root
      host_all: yes
      password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"

  - name: Create a new database with name 'test'
    mysql_db:
      login_user: root
      login_password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"
      login_unix_socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
      name: test
      state: present

  - name: Create database user with name 'test' and password 'Test@1123' with all database privileges
    mysql_user:
      name: test
      password: Test@1123
      priv: '*.test:ALL'
      state: present
```

While running this playbook, I am getting below error -

```
TASK [Mysql Configuration - Resetting RootPassword] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, u\"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

I have checked /root/.my.cnf file has been updated with correct username & password.

I tried to run `mysql -u root -p`. This has been successful without any password. But while trying to run `mysql -u 'root'@'localhost' -p`, it is not allowing to get into mysql with or without password.

I know this can be fixed several ways manually. But how to fix this issue with Ansible. May be I am doing some silly mistake. But unable to figure it out. I have also tried without /root/.my.cnf file and without socket file also. But facing same issue.

---

***UPDATE:***

I fixed the issue by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433295/unable-to-change-password-for-root-account-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_user_module.html#examples mysql_user_module documentation.

Here's probably what you want to achieve:

```
- name: "Mysql Configuration - Resetting RootPassword"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: actual_root_mysql_password
    host: ''
    name: root
    password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"
```

Comment: I tried this also. But somehow didn't work. I fixed this by following this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433295/unable-to-change-password-for-root-account-ansible